# Display the selected data in .txt file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've a table named "range_Stat" in the database. I need to select the range which having a status "new" and generate the new txt file. the txt file will contain the start range and end range that have been assigned to the application.

This is the example of structure for the table.

[image: table structure image]

I've tried to generate the .txt file. However, it displays all the range with status 'new'. All I need is to select the first range in the database with status 'new' and display the range in the .txt file.

The code that I've tried:

```
private void genTxtFile()
{
    dbConnect();
    SqlCommand cmd_rg;
    SqlDataReader dataReader;
    String sql = "";

    sqlstmt = "SELECT start_rg, end_rg FROM range_Stat WHERE status = 'new' ";
    cmd_rg = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

    dataReader = cmd_rg.ExecuteReader();

    using (StreamWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"..\range\new_range.txt"))
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            tw.WriteLine("[Range]");
            tw.WriteLine("Start Range: {0}", dataReader["start_rg"]);
            tw.WriteLine("End Range: {0}", dataReader["end_rg"]);
        }
    }
    cmd_rg.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are comparing to 'New' not 'new'

Comment: sorry. i've updated the code.

Comment: i'm no sql expert but can you not just do sqlstmt = "SELECT TOP(1) start_rg, end_rg FROM range_Stat WHERE status = 'new' ";

Comment: If you just want the first row that matches 'new' then let sql do it for you, perhaps using TOP or LIMIT:

https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_top.asp

Your sql is selecting all rows where status = 'new'

@TimRutter had the answer, sorry, just refreshed page and saw it

Comment: First, run that SQL query in Adminer or in MSSQL Manager studio and see if it is correct. If not, ask a question about the query (not dependent on PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just amend your sql statement to this

```
sqlstmt = "SELECT TOP(1) start_rg, end_rg FROM range_Stat WHERE status = 'new' ";
```